# In Nginx docker how do we see log only from error.log

Tags: docker, nginx

Nginx Docker file is configured to send error.log to /dev/stderr.

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log 
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

When we run `docker logs --tail=10 -f nginx` it show a combination of both error log and access log. Is there a docker command so I can only see the logs of error.log or stderr?

Comment: Are you using the default NGINX docker image? or one of your own?

Comment: I use `docker logs --tail=50 nginx | grep '\[error\]'`, note that it will show errors in the last 50 logs (it does **not** show the "last 50 errors").

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this command to get only error.log:

```
docker logs -f nginx 1>/dev/null
```

And this one for access.log:

```
docker logs -f nginx 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Dockerfile snippet you added in your question, it looks like you are using the official NGINX image.

> The NGINX image is configured to send the main NGINX access and error logs to the Docker log collector by default. This is done by linking them to stdout and stderr, which causes all messages from both logs to be stored in the file/var/lib/docker/containers/\/\-json.log on the Docker Host.

**One method is to use the docker API.**

You can enable the docker API and query the logs that way, in `/etc/default/docker`:

```
DOCKEROPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock'
```

Then:

```
http://<docker host>:4243/containers/<container name>/logs?stderr=1
```

See:

https://www.docker.com/blog/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/

Comment: the file /etc/default/docker is supposed to be in the host machine right? I could not find it in Ubuntu 18.04. could it be in any other location?

Comment: This can be really easier